# Opendir and Wordpress Path

Tags: plugins, directory

I wrote a simple function to get the contents in a folder (called templates) in my wordpress plugin, but am having problems getting the path to work (thus the function always dies).  My question is:  Is there a wordpress function or something that will give me the path to my plugin as required for the opendir function to work?

```
 function get_templates(){

    $path =   '[path to my plugin]/templates';

$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Cannot open the damn file $path");

 while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {

  if(substr($file,-3) == "php" )

   continue;

  $TheLinkedFile = $path."/".$file;
 if(file_exists($TheLinkedFile)) {

echo $TheLinkedFile.'<br>';
 } else {
echo "nothing";
 }
 }

closedir($dir_handle);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example...

```
 //..path/to/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin-basedir/
 $path  = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__); 

 //..directory within your plugin 
 $path .= 'templates';                

 //..continue with your script...
 $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Cannot open the damn file $path");
```

## UPDATE

I tested the rest of your script by the way, to see if it in fact did read the directory and list files with the *.php extension and it wouldn't work.

Instead after modifying it to;

```
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Cannot open the damn file $path");

while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {

    //get length of filename inc. extension
    $length_of_filename = strlen($file); 

    //strip all but last three characters from file name to get extension
    $ext = substr($file, -3, $length_of_filename); 

    if($ext == "php" ) {

    $TheLinkedFile = $path."/".$file;

        if(file_exists($TheLinkedFile)) {
            echo $TheLinkedFile.'<br>';
        } else {
            echo "nothing";
        }
    }

}

closedir($dir_handle);
```

It works...

Answer (score 0):

I recently used the following code for batch processing some images but you can modify it to suit your needs:

```
<?php
$dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'path/to/files/';
foreach ( glob( $dir . '*.php' ) as $file ) {
    $file_name = basename( $file );
    // do what you want with  $file - no need to check for existence
}
```

Note: The purpose of my answer is to show an alternative way of doing this. An example use of this code can be found [here](http://tracker.josephleedy.me/projects/project-manager/repository/revisions/0.2.1/entry/classes/class-project-post-type.php) on line 253.